# Why is the Eq (GADT) case giving me a type error?

Tags: haskell, gadt

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module Main where

data CudaExpr x where
  C :: x -> CudaExpr x

  Add :: Num x => CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr x
  Sub :: Num x => CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr x
  Mul :: Num x => CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr x
  Div :: (Num x, Fractional x) => CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr x

  Eq :: (Eq x) => CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr Bool
  -- LessThan :: CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr Bool
  -- If :: CudaExpr Bool -> CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr x

eval (C x) = x
eval (Add a b) = eval a + eval b
eval (Sub a b) = eval a - eval b
eval (Mul a b) = eval a * eval b
eval (Div a b) = eval a / eval b

eval (Eq a b) = eval a == eval b
-- eval (LessThan a b) = eval a < eval b
-- eval (If cond true false) = if eval cond then eval true else eval false


main :: IO ()
main = print "Hello"
```

It does not seem to be the monomorphism restriction. This is what error do I get:

```
* Could not deduce: x ~ Bool
  from the context: (t ~ Bool, Eq x)
    bound by a pattern with constructor:
               Eq :: forall x. Eq x => CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr Bool,
             in an equation for `eval'
    at app\Main.hs:23:7-12
  `x' is a rigid type variable bound by
    a pattern with constructor:
      Eq :: forall x. Eq x => CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr x -> CudaExpr Bool,
    in an equation for `eval'
    at app\Main.hs:23:7
  Expected type: CudaExpr x -> Bool
    Actual type: CudaExpr t -> t
* In the first argument of `(==)', namely `eval a'
  In the expression: eval a == eval b
  In an equation for `eval': eval (Eq a b) = eval a == eval b
* Relevant bindings include
    b :: CudaExpr x (bound at app\Main.hs:23:12)
    a :: CudaExpr x (bound at app\Main.hs:23:10)
```

Comment: What would you say the return type of `eval` is? It can't be `Num x => x`, because `eval (Eq (C 3) (C 3))` needs to return `True :: Bool`. It can't be `Bool` because `eval (Add (C 3) (C 3))` needs to return `6 :: Num x => x`.

Comment: Well, obviously it should depend on the structure of CudaExpr passed into the functions. I do not see why it should not be one or the other. I know the above example is possible to encode using phantom types, so are the typeclass constraints I've set the problem here? ...No, even if I comment out all the cases but the `Eq` it still does not work.

Comment: Ok, I get it. It was something like the monomorhism restriction after all. Once I add the type annotation `eval :: CudaExpr x -> x`, the error goes away. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: GADTs and type inference do not mix well: always add an explicit type annotation when you pattern match over a GADT

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [GHC docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=gadt#ghc-flag--XGADTs):

> The general principle is this: *type refinement is only carried out based on user-supplied type annotations*. So if no type signature is supplied for `eval`, no type refinement happens, and lots of obscure error messages will occur.

In other words, when we pattern match on a GADT type (either through multiple equations or with a `case`), providing an explicit type annotation is necessary.

As a thought experiment consider

```
data T a where C :: Char -> T Char

f (C c) = c
```

What is the right typing?

```
f :: T a    -> a
f :: T a    -> Char
f :: T Char -> Char
```

The last one is more specific, the first two are strictly more general. However, none of the first two is more general than the other -- GHC can not pick the "best" one.

GADTs are not too special in this. Most advanced features require type annotations: GADTs, higher-rank types, type families at least do.